# Azure KeyVault: How to set access policy in parallel

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

While creating access policy using `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy` command, getting error : The operation failed because the  'Key Vault' changed from the point the operation began. This can happen if parallel operations are being performed on the. To prevent this error, serialize the operations so that only one operation is performed on the at a time. Follow this link for more information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2147741.

Multiple scripts are running in parallel to set different sets of access policies on the same keyvault causing this conflict.

Is there any other way to set access policy in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, if you run the commands in parallel to set the access policy, it will cause the `ConflictError`.

So if you want to set a bunch of users/service principals/security groups in the access policy at the same time, a better option is to use the [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/), you can deploy access policies to an existing key vault without redeploying the entire key vault template, see this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vault-create-template?tabs=CLI#add-an-access-policy-to-a-key-vault-resource-manager-template). In this sample, there is just one object, to add several objects, simply add them like below, modify the `tenantId`, `objectId`, `permissions` to yours.

```
"resources": [
     {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "properties": {
      "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "objectId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "UnwrapKey",
                                "WrapKey"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "ManageContacts",
                                "ManageIssuers",
                                "GetIssuers",
                                "ListIssuers",
                                "SetIssuers",
                                "DeleteIssuers"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "tenantId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "objectId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Import",
                                "Update",
                                "Create"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "tenantId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "objectId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "ManageContacts",
                                "ManageIssuers",
                                "GetIssuers",
                                "ListIssuers",
                                "SetIssuers",
                                "DeleteIssuers"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "tenantId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "objectId": "xxxxxxx",
                        "permissions": {
                            "secrets": [
                                "List",
                                "Get"
                            ],
                            "keys": [],
                            "certificates": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
       }
  ]
```

Comment: what if I run multiple ARM templates in parallel on the same keyvault? Will there be any conflicts?

Comment: @AniketPrashar Of course there will be conflicts, but why you need to run multiple templates on the same keyvault? Why not include all the things you need in one template?

Comment: I have multiple web apps in different resource groups and I'm deploying them in parallel to save time.

Comment: @AniketPrashar What does this have to do with the keyvault template?

Comment: Let's say, I have 5 RGs having 50 web apps each. After creating these web apps in parallel I have to perform certain time-consuming operation on each web app in diffeent RGs that requires keyvault access policy to be there in the keyvault before the time-consuming operations begin.

Comment: @AniketPrashar You mean you need to add every system-assigned identity of the web apps to the keyvault? If so, I think you could use user-assigned identity instead, bind it to each web app, then just add it to the access policy once. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-portal

Comment: It seems that user assigned identity isn't supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: @AniketPrashar If you want to use the keyvault reference feature of web app, it does not support the user-assigned identity, anyway you could not do operations aganist the access policy at the same time, you could create all the web apps first, then add the system-assigned identities together to the keyvault template.